# Using a hash as a primary key?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to store the list of services for multiple computers. I thought I would create one table to hold a list of all possible tables, a table for all possible computers and then a table to link a service to a computer.

I was thinking to keep the full services list unique, I could possibly use a hash of the executable as the primary key for the service, but i'm not sure if there would be any downsides to this (note that the hashing is only for identification. Not for any types of security purposes). I was thinking rather than using a binary field as the primary/foreign key, that I would store the value as a base 64 encoded sha512, and using an `nvarchar(88)`. Something similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE Services
(
  ServiceHash nvarchar(88) NOT NULL,
  ServiceName nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
  ServiceDescription nvarchar(256),
  PRIMARY KEY (ServiceHash)
)
```

Is there any inherent problems with this solution? (I will be using a SQL 2008 database and generally accessing it via C#.Net).

Comment: hashes are not guaranteed to be unique. Just use a GUID

Comment: `Nvarchar(88)` - that's a potentially very wide (and variable length) key; if you use that as your clustering key on that table (which the PK is, by default), you won't be very happy with the performance of that table!

Comment: @marc_s gets better. As theat is a base64 encoded number in the hash, the N part of the varchar is never used by definition, so you double storage totally useless. Good point, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a hash is per definition NOT UNIQUE. It is unlikely you get a collision, but it IS possible. As a result, you can not use the hash only, which means the whole hash id is a dead end.

Use a normal ID field, use a unique constraint with index on the ServiceName.

Comment: Hard collisions are really rare.

Comment: At 256 bits (maybe even a little less) they are rare enough not to have to worry about accounting for them in your project; the mere discovery of a collision would be a major threat to worldwide digital security

Answer (score 0):

From a performance point of view, having a non-incremental primary key would cause your clustered index to get fragmented rather quickly.

I recommend either:

1. Use an `INT` or `BIGINT` surrogate PK, with auto-increment.
2. Use a [sequential GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as a PK. Not as fast for indexing as an `INT` but incremental, therefore low fragmentation in time.

You can then play with non-clustered indexes on your other columns, including the one storing the hashes. Being `VARCHAR` you can also full-text index it and then do an exact matching when looking for a specific hash.

But, if possible, use a numerical hash instead and make a non-clustered index on it.

And of course, consider what `@TomTom` mentioned below.